# Using React hooks conditionally in Next JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

EDIT: This question was originally about a Type error when using React hooks in a CodeSandbox environment but I've updated it so that it's useful to future visitors.

I'm using the following code to try to create a hook for using the scroll position to animate the height of a website header. The trouble is that I've tried various methods to get it to stop it erroring on the server but keep getting various errors (despite checking for the existence of the window object).

There was some example code in my original question and I've updated the following Code Sandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/p5y6262qzm

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Object(…) is not a function

first of all I know that there are other questions with this title but there seems to be multiple causes and I can't find an answer that covers my particular case.

The simplest (incomplete) code I can use to generate the example is this...

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const useScrollPosition = () => {
  // Store the state
  const [scrollPos, setScrollPos] = useState(window.pageYOffset);

  return scrollPos;
};

export default useScrollPosition;
```

Although there is a more complete example of what I am trying to do in this codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/p5y6262qzm

I'm guessing it's something real simple, I just can't seem to put my finger on it.

Comment: The problem here is that React is not up to date. It should be 16.7 alpha. You can check that `React.version` is 16.5.2. I would expect `useState` to cause `undefined is not a function`, I can't say why it says `Object(...)`. Any way, the problem is codesandbox Next.js template.

Comment: Ah, of course. That didn't occur to me as my project has the correct version, I was using code sandbox to make a demo to illustrate an unconnected problem when I ran into this. Would you like to convert this to a proper answer or do you think I should just delete the question?

Comment: Hmm, actually that still doesn't seem to work. I've added two different versions of the alpha , watched it NPM and refreshed the page both times.

Comment: Consider updating the question, so it would be more suited to your current problem. I've tried to address it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This Next.js setup results in

> TypeError: window.addEventListener is not a function

error on client side, because `window` global is shadowed by local variable:

```
const window = window || {
  width: 0,
  height: 0,
  pageXOffset: 0,
  pageYOffset: 0
};
```

It should be:

```
const w = (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window) || {
  width: 0,
  height: 0,
  pageXOffset: 0,
  pageYOffset: 0
};
```

This will result in mocked object being used during server-side rendering and `window` being used during client-side rendering.

A better solution would be to avoid using components that are specific to client side, e.g. with `react-no-ssr`. Since it's not a good practice to apply hooks (`useScrollPosition` hook) conditionally, it's a component that uses this hook that needs to be rendered conditionally.

Comment: Thanks again Estus, I'm pretty sure your answer is correct but it's my fault for not understanding it. the "w" object in your example will either be "true" or {width...}. How do you ensure that the W object is used on the server and the window object used on the client? Sounds simple, but every attempt I've made to do things conditionally on the server has failed. Unfortunately no-ssr is not an option as the component which needs to change height dependent on scroll position is the site header which needs to exist for SEO reasons.

Comment: I seem to have fixed it by putting "if (typeof window === "undefined") return 0;" as the first line in my hook function.